# PDF of $\theta1$ - $\theta2$ for $\theta1$ and $\theta2$ i.i.d Uniform RVs on [0,$2\pi$)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to obtain the PDF of $\theta1$ - $\theta2$ where $\theta1$ and $\theta2$ are both i.i.d Uniform RVs on [0,$2\pi$).

The added condition here is that every operation is done modulo 2$\pi$.

I tried to use convolution and follow a similar process as finding the PDF of X+Y but with no result.
Any suggestion ??

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004535/obtain-the-joint-pdf-of-theta-1-theta-2-and-theta-1-where-theta) today I answered exactly the same question.